# Bash / take word with constant prefix

Tags: bash

I have the following line:

```
70947344da  709473,production-a-709473,stg-a-709473  2018-08-27T10:54:30
```

My input is: `production-a` which is a constant prefix. I wish to get as an output: `production-a-709473`

Tried to use `sed` with `sed "s/.*/production-a/`" but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression is incorrect.

You need to capture `production-a` followed by a certain number of digits (more than one), leading to the following regular expression: `production-a-\d+`, which can also be rewritten as `production-a-[0-9]+`

To extract this output, you can use the grep command. An example would be the following:

`grep -o 'production-a-[0-9]\+'`

`\+` here is used to escape the `+` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GNU `grep`, with the `--only-matching` option (or `-o` for short) to "print  only  the  matched  (non-empty) parts of a matching line".

Assuming the only delimiter to be used is a comma, you can do this:

```
grep --only-matching "$input[^,]*"
```

Here I've assumed `$input` is your prefix, and that you have validated it to not contain a regex.

Comment: thanks, but it also print me the part which is after the matching word `production-a-709473,stg-a-709473  2018-08-27T10:54:30`

Comment: @MiddleWare Did you include the regex with `[^,]*` which says "any number of characters that is not a comma"? It certainly worked for me, see https://ideone.com/3R8oz6